# phpstan - return a generic

Tags: php, generics, return-type, phpstan

I feel stupid asking such a simple question, but I am clearly missing something basic.

The CollectionOrdered class below is meant to "carry a payload" and the point of HasPayloadInterface is to encapsulate operations for all classes which carry a payload, not just CollectionOrdered.

I have a CollectionOrderedFactory which makes a CollectionOrdered object.  I would have thought that the return type for the makeCollection method in the factory would be CollectionOrdered<PayloadType>, as I have written below.

BUT

Phpstan comes back with "makeCollection() should return CollectionOrdered<PayloadType> but instead returns CollectionOrdered<HasPayloadInterface>".  I just don't understand where the problem lies..

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Class HasPayloadInterface
 * @template PayloadType
 */
interface HasPayloadInterface
{
}

/**
 * Class CollectionOrdered
 * @template PayloadType of HasPayloadInterface
 * @implements HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType>
 */
class CollectionOrdered implements HasPayloadInterface
{
}

/**
 * Class CollectionOrderedFactory
 * @template PayloadType of HasPayloadInterface
 */
class CollectionOrderedFactory
{
    /**
     * makeCollection
     * @return CollectionOrdered<PayloadType>
     */
    public function makeCollection(): CollectionOrdered
    {
        return new CollectionOrdered();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues in your code:

1. This part looks wrong to me because `PayloadType` refers to the generic interface `HasPayloadInterface`, but its type is not specified:

```php
/**
 * Class CollectionOrdered
 * @template PayloadType of HasPayloadInterface
 * @implements HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType>
 */
class CollectionOrdered implements HasPayloadInterface
```

If we substitute `PayloadType` for its value, we'll obtain: `@implements HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType of HasPayloadInterface>`. In this expression it is apparent that the type parameter for the second reference to `HasPayloadInterface` is missing. If we add the missing type, we'll get something like this:

```
@implements HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType of HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType>>
```

But `PayloadType` is of `HasPayloadInterface,` so we end up with a cyclic reference.

I guess there might be a typo in your code. I would instead expect to see a separate type for the payload, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @template PayloadType of string
 * @implements HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType>
 */
class CollectionOrdered implements HasPayloadInterface
```

2. There is no way to deduce the `PayloadType` to anything other than `HasPayloadInterface` in the following code:

```php
/**
 * Class CollectionOrderedFactory
 * @template PayloadType of HasPayloadInterface
 */
class CollectionOrderedFactory
```

That is because there is no way for the user to specify the `PayloadType` (not even implicitly).

The error goes away when you allow the user to set the `PayloadType` in one way or another. For instance, in the following code, classes accept type information via constructor arguments:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @template PayloadType of PayloadInterface
 * @implements HasPayloadInterface<PayloadType>
 */
class CollectionOrdered implements HasPayloadInterface
{
    /**
     * @param class-string<PayloadType> $payloadType
     */
    public function __construct(private string $payloadType) {}

    public function getPayload(): string
    {
        return $this->payloadType;
    }
}

/**
 * @template PayloadType of PayloadInterface
 */
class CollectionFactory
{
    /**
     * @param class-string<PayloadType> $payloadType
     */
    public function __construct(private string $payloadType) {}

    /**
     * @return CollectionOrdered<PayloadType>
     */
    public function makeCollection(): CollectionOrdered
    {
        return new CollectionOrdered($this->payloadType);
    }
}

/**
 * Class HasPayloadInterface
 * @template PayloadType
 */
interface HasPayloadInterface
{
}

interface PayloadInterface
{
    public function getPayload(): string;
}

class SimplePayload implements PayloadInterface
{
    public function __construct(private string $payload) {}

    public function getPayload(): string
    {
        return $this->payload;
    }
}
```

I admit that the code above is relatively useless, and you'll probably need another way of passing the type information into the classes, but it fixes the issue:

```
$ phpstan analyze --no-progress --no-ansi --level=9 -- test.php

 [OK] No errors
```

Here is how one could create a `CollectionOrdered<SimplePayload>`:

```php
$factory = new CollectionFactory(SimplePayload::class);
$collection = $factory->makeCollection();
```